# how can I take certain elements in a larger data frame and make another data Frame with these elements in python?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a project that uses a data Frame of almost 24000 basketball games from the years 2004-2021. what I want to do in the end is make a single data Frame that has only 1 row for each year and the column values will be the mean for that category. What I have so far is a mask function that can separate by year but I want to make a for loop that will go through the list of years, get the mean of that, and then concatenate them into a new data frame. The code might help explain this better.

```
## now i want to seperate this into data sets based on year so ill make a function this will be used to seperate by year. in my original dataset "SEASON" is the year.

def mask(year):
    mask = stats['SEASON']== year
    
    year_mask= stats[mask]
    return year_mask
```

how can I possibly make this into a loop that seperates by year, finds mean clues of all columns in that year, and combines them into 1 data from that should have 18 rows that span from 2004-2021?

Comment: Pandas data frames have lots of functions built in like .mean(). Is stats a Pandas dataframe? What do you mean by mean for that category?

Comment: @SirNibblelll yes stats is a pandas dataframe. for example for the year 2021 there are 1076 rows (each individual game) and 11 columns that contain observations for things like home team points, away team points, season, free throw percentage, etc. So what I want is 1 row for the year 2021 that contains just the average of all these columns so I can plot this data without there being 24000 different data points. Does that make it a little easier to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Pandas dataframes it's best to let pandas do the work for you.

I assume you want to calculate the mean of some category in your dataframe grouped by the year. To do this we can create a function like so:

```
def foo(df, category):
    return df.groupby(by=["year"])[category].mean()
```

If you want to mean all the categories just use:

```
df.groupby(by=["year"]).mean()
```

Comment: Thank you so much that did just the trick!

Comment: No problem, fancy flagging this as the answer? :)

Comment: @SirNibblelll one more question for you if you have the time. So I copied the code you have above and now have data frame that is grouped by year and has the mean values just like I wanted. Now I come across the issue where I cannot graph this because the year is not a column anymore. when I do stats.index it also shows the name of it is "Years"